# How deals website works

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

Im new to web design and development.

I would like to know how the deals websites work technically.

What i mean is how the deals are automatically fetched from various e commerce websites such as amazon and ebay.

And also please suggest me the best solution to implement the above website.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nobody is going to write a thesis into how these things work and include an extra section into how to go about and implement it - Go through tutorials starting with the basics of web development

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Thanks for the reply. Can you please let me know the high level solution in may be one or two sentences so that i will go and do my r&d on the same.  Once again thanks for your time in advance

Comment: RESTful API, web services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the keyword in case of automatically fetching data from any other websites is `Web Scraping`.

#### What is Web Scraping?

> Web scraping (web harvesting or web data extraction) is a computer >software technique of extracting information from websites. [Source & Further Reading: Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)

Find Web Scraping you can fetch data from chosen websites to gather a solid database, which then could become accessible via RESTful APIs like Nicholas commented above.

On the Web you can find several tutorials and examples of how to do web scraping. A very basic one would be on the blog of [miguelgrinberg.com](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-python).

Another, somewhat older post on [optimum7.com](http://www.optimum7.com/internet-marketing/ecommerce/how-to-scrape-and-crawl-data-from-websites-like-amazon-com-and-ebay.html) describes your interest of accessing amazon or ebay.

Good luck to you and happy learning